# JS documentation of numerical syntax

Tags: javascript

I have seen a syntax such as the following before:

```
var mynum = new Number();
var temp = (+mynum);  //this line is what i am curious about
var text = temp.toPrecision(3);
```

Can anyone tell me what this + syntax means?
What I have found is that in some JS implementations, it is somehow necessary as it ensures that the number defined in mynum is valid.

Thanks,
jml

Comment: Simple unary arithmetic operator like in `+1` or `-2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+` is a unary operator which is used to coerce data types into numbers. Unary meaning it only needs one operand.

`new Date` returns an object, applying `+` coerces it into a timestamp eg `1277504628812`

`new Number` returns an object, applying `+` coerces it into the numeric literal `0`.

See: http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.4.6

This is the ECMAScript documentation, which is the subset of Javascript, in HTML format.

Comment: I can't say I understand why that's needed when the previous line is declaring "mynum" to be of type Number.

Comment: The person was probably just being real explicit I suppose, I doubt there's any sort of bug in JScript ( MS implementation ) seeing as how those are very trivial statements.

Comment: If `mynum` were a string, then `(+mynum)` makes it a number.